How can I check whether my computer system is capable of running Wayland?
When I check my system on whether it is running X11 or Wayland via echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE it responds that it is running X11.
How can I check whether it is capable of running Wayland?

What linux distro are you running? what DE are you running?

Debian 11 and KDE 5

I'm sure Debian 11 used Wayland ... maybe it's Debian 12, you know, the current one.

Actually Wayland has been default since Debian 10
